# JavaScript ADODBE connection update query not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server

JavaScript ADODBE connection how to put or between them in query. Need help:

```
rs.Open("update customer set Name='" + txtname + "',F_Name='" + txtfname + "',Cnic='" + txtcnic + "',Dues='" + txtdues + "',Fees= '" + txtfees + "'  where Id = '" + id + "'", connection);
```

Comment: the txtname , txtfname, txtcnic, txtdues, txtfees are the textboxes

Comment: Please add body of comment to the question, then remove the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
rs.Open("update customer set Name='" + txtname + "',F_Name='" + txtfname + "',Cnic='" + txtcnic + "',Dues='" + txtdues + "',Fees= '" + txtfees + "'  where Id = '" + id + "'", connection);
```

Comment: sir i need your help can you plz give me your mail id

Comment: madam i need that i show the edit button in first column of the each row  please madam i need help

Comment: madam i am new here the code i too many and it will not be inserted here in comment

Comment: document.write("<table>");
   document.write("<tr>");
  for (var i = 0; i < rs.Fields.Count ; i++) 
  {
   
    document.write("<th style='color: #009900;'>" + rs.Fields(i).Name + "</th>");
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
 
  while (!rs.EOF) {
   document.write("<tr>");
   
   for (var i = 0; i < rs.Fields.Count; i++)
    {
     
    document.write("<td >" + rs.Fields(i) +  "</td>");
    
    }
   document.write("</tr>");
   rs.movenext();
  }
  document.write("</table>");

Comment: this is the table through the data come from the ado connection

Comment: madam plz i need your help

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<table>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (var i = 0; i < rs.Fields.Count ; i++) 
    {

         document.write("<th style='color: #009900;'>" + rs.Fields(i).Name + "</th>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");

    while (!rs.EOF) {
        document.write("<tr>");

        for (var i = 0; i < rs.Fields.Count; i++)
         {

         document.write("<td >" + rs.Fields(i) +  "</td>");

      }
        document.write("</tr>");
        rs.movenext();
    }
```

document.write("");

Comment: var objConnection = new ActiveXObject("adodb.connection");
   var strConn = "driver={sql server};server=DESKTOP-IA5UQ36;database=arif;uid=;password=";
   objConnection.Open(strConn);
   var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
   var strQuery = "SELECT Id , Name,F_Name,Cnic, Dues,Fees FROM  customer ORDER BY  Id";
     rs.Open(strQuery, objConnection);
   rs.MoveFirst();

Comment: the above is the connection

Comment: need the edit button in the first column of each row